# facebox close button on top right corner

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery, facebox

Hi I'm using facebox plugin to display iframe link.
I want to change the style of my close button. I want to show it on Top can any one please help with CSS part. 
I want to make facebox draggable is it possible to do soo..

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Dragging facebox window i used jquery UI's draggable plugin like this,

$(document).bind('reveal.facebox', function () {
            $("#facebox").draggable();
        })

thats it.

For close button CSS im using,

## facebox .close-image

{
            background-color: inherit;
            position: absolute;
            right: -2px;
            width: 24px;
            height: 22px;
            background-image: url(../images/close.png);
            cursor: pointer;
            z-index: 1103;
            display: none;
    }